# TextArea.setBounds property not working in a fixed position

Tags: java, swing

I'm working on a basic IDE project in this project. 
I want to add a `TextArea` in a fixed position but setBounds property is not working.

```
TextArea a=new TextArea(30,120);

a.setBackground(Color.black);
a.setForeground(Color.white);
p3=new JPanel();
p3.setBackground(Color.pink);
p3.setBounds(180,100,1350,650);
p3.setVisible(true);
f.add(p3);
p3.add(a);
```

[image]

Here, black screen is the textarea but I want to see  this text area as all the pink screen position is `(180,100,1350,650)`

Comment: Avoid using `null` or "absolute" layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Comment: *"but i want to see this text area as all the pink screen position"* - Add the `JTextArea` to the "pink" panel and use a `BorderLayout` on the "pink" panel

Comment: so how  i set the position of TextArea

Comment: ok thanku i will be try

Comment: BTW try with JEditorPane, I think it's better.

Comment: @chilltouch `JEditorPane` is for display styled documents, in particular HTML, `JTextPane` can slo display styled documents and `JTextArea` is used for plain text

Comment: TextArea is not Swing, it is an AWT component. Use JTextArea for Swing.